# pdfLaTeX hangs with tikz-cd and comma in the arrow label

Tags: pdftex, tikz-cd, bugs

When I compile a file containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}\ar[r,","] &\end{tikzcd}$:$
\end{document}
```

with the command `pdflatex  -interaction=nonstopmode  file.tex`, the compilation hangs instead of giving me an error message.

Where should I report this?

(I'm using texlive 2020 on ubuntu 21.04)

Answer (score 3):

Not a bug.  When `tikz-cd` parses comma-separated options, your option list `r,","` becomes three items: `r`, `"`, and `"`, and you can see how wrong that goes.  You would usually get a low-level error:

```latex
! Argument of \tikz@quote@@parser has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \begin{tikzcd}\ar[r,","] & b\end{tikzcd}
                                            $:$
?
```

but with `-interaction=nonstopmode` you just ignore that error and hope for the best, but here TeX gets into an infinite loop and hangs.

To use a comma there, wrap it in braces:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd} a \ar[r,"{,}"] & b \end{tikzcd}$:$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'm using pdflatex through latexmk through the latex-workshop plugin in vscode. In vscode, the command hanging has the compilation doesn't terminate, and even when closing vscode a pdflatex process keeps running. So where is the bug? Apart from the process running after the program closes, do you think it's acceptable for latex IDEs to hang?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, I meant "Where in the chain is the bug if not in pdflatex"?

Comment: @user313032 Definitely _not_ in pdflatex.  I'd blame the plugin for two things:  1) running with `nonstopmode`, because that ignores any compilation errors, and 2) for not killing the job on exit and leaving it running.  As for “[is it] acceptable for latex IDEs to hang?”, my answer is “it's their own fault”.  LaTeX documents don't usually enter an infinite loop out of the blue (when they do, the blame is on a package or on the document author), but if some compilation error happens and you ignore it, what happens next is pure chance (an infinite loop is in the realm of possibilities).

Comment: @user313032 But on the other hand, an IDE that gives the user a command line to interact with a TeX error would not be a very good IDE, and neither would be one that halts compilation on an error, so maybe the blame is on users for using IDEs in the first place ;-) (that's not to be taken seriously :)

Answer (score 0):

Braces are needed, and the tikzcd documentation says this explicitly:

> Similarly, a label can receive additional options via the syntax
> "⟨label text⟩"⟨label options⟩. Both ⟨label text⟩ and ⟨label options⟩
> need to be enclosed in curly braces if they contain commas.

There is a reference to the main TikZ documentation on labels (section 17.10.4), which discusses the alternative syntax of `label={...}`, but that does not appear to work inside a tikzcd `\arrow[...]` construct (so you couldn't write `\ar[r,label={,}]`, for example, but `\ar[r,"{,}"]` does work).

Comment: The word “label” is used very differently depending on context. What TikZ-CD considers to be labels along a path are just edge nodes, i.e. `edge node = {node[auto] {,}}` but TikZ provdes a shortcut for that: `edge label = {,}`. However, this wouldn't include the `every label` style from TikZ-CD. The `label` key is a “label” on a node and the manual says so: “When this option is given to a node operation, it causes another node to be added to the path after the current node has been finished.”.

Comment: The solution: using curly braces was already given in the other answer.

Comment: yes i know that braces are needed. but in reasonable programming languages the compiler doesn't just hang even when supplied with incorrect syntax, that's why i naively thought i had discovered a bug